# Generating HTML within a tag by JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap

if I have a block of html code, I wanna use a loop to generate `<div item>` and place it in the body tag. I know how to write a script to write html. But how do i tell my script to place it in the body tag?

I am using Boostrap also I'm open to both jquery and pure js solution.

```
<body>
<div id="myCarousel" class="carousel slide">
      <div class="carousel-inner">
        <div class="item active">
          <img src="../assets/img/examples/slide-01.jpg" alt="">
          <div class="container">
            <div class="carousel-caption">
              <h1>Example headline.</h1>
              <p class="lead">vehicula ut id elit.</p>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>

        <div class="item">
          <img src="../assets/img/examples/slide-03.jpg" alt="">
          <div class="container">
            <div class="carousel-caption">
              <p class="lead">ies vehicula ut id elit.</p>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
<body>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well the less desirable way is:

```
document.write(...)
```

Or..

```
document.body.appendChild(...)
```

If you're using something like jquery you could do:

```
$('body').append(...)
```

Comment: That has to have been the most diplomatic choice of an answer I have ever seen :D +1

Answer (score 5):

```
var div = document.createElement("div");
document.body.appendChild(div);
```

Answer (score 2):

With `data` being the html:

```
$('body').append(data);
```

Comment: javascript and jquery have become interchangable these days...<sigh>

Comment: @Raidenace he tagged it bootstrap, which I believe depends on jquery

Comment: @Jean-BernardPellerin Yep, any Javascript features definitely depend on jQuery. I think the CSS doesn't though, not sure

Comment: @Raidenace - From http://twitter.github.io/bootstrap/getting-started.html#file-structure: "Please note that all JavaScript plugins require jQuery to be included."

Comment: @Ian, Jean - I was not critiquing your answer. Just saying how Jquery has become for JS libs what facebook has become for social networking :)

Comment: Chillax, all you jQuery lovers!! :)

Comment: @Raidenace I wasn't trying to argue/challenge anything, I was just supporting Jean's claim that bootstrap depends on jQuery, that's all :)

Answer (score 2):

Try jQuery .append
Here's a link....

http://api.jquery.com/append/

Using only Javascript:

```
<div id="div1">
<p id="p1">This is a paragraph.</p>
<p id="p2">This is another paragraph.</p>
</div>

<script>
var para=document.createElement("p");
var node=document.createTextNode("This is new.");
para.appendChild(node);

var element=document.getElementById("div1");
element.appendChild(para);
</script>
```

Comment: What if the OP can't use jquery?

Comment: Still the question is tagged javascript.

Comment: @Gabe It's also tagged "twitter-bootstrap", which implies that jQuery is used. Meaning, the question isn't tagged completely correct. I do think the other answers (which provide several options, not just jQuery) are more complete/better.

Comment: @Gabe - It's now tagged "jQuery". Since this person is using Bootstrap, jQuery is implied. Please see http://twitter.github.io/bootstrap/getting-started.html#file-structure for more details.  With that said, this answer could still be improved by showing how one might tackle the problem in JavaScript, but I don't believe that's required to answer this particular question. +1

Comment: @jmort253 I get it that twitter-bootstrap makes use of jquery, but that doesn't mean the OP is or that it's clear for other's to make that assumption. Being more definitive is better that expecting other to assume or know everything about everything.

Comment: @Gabe - Agreed, but since we shouldn't make assumptions that he is using jQuery, it seems contradictory to assume that he isn't. I'd ideally prefer the op to come back and clarify, and I left a comment for the op in regards to that.  However, if he doesn't update us, I don't think we can vilify jQuery answers simply because it's ambiguous. In short, a JavaScript answer is most ideal, but an answer that utilizes tools the op has already imported wouldn't be necessarily incorrect. It looks like he edited his post to clarify. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 2):

You can use [Node.appendChild](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/DOM/Node.appendChild)

```
var element = document.createElement("div");

element.textContent = "some text";
document.body.appendChild(element);
```

On [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Xotic750/PNQp9/)

Answer (score 2):

First, you need function that allows you to select elements by classes. [`document.querySelectorAll`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/DOM/document.querySelectorAll) should do the trick but it is not supported on some browsers (older versions of IE for example).

You can then use the [`Node.appendChild`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/DOM/Node.appendChild) function to *move* the selected elements. The code would look like this:

```
var items = document.querySelectorAll("div.item"), i;
for (i = 0; i < items.length; i++) {
    document.body.appendChild(items[i]);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can loop over your array to create the divs you would like. The example below shows getting the body tag and creating divs then adding them to the body. You can also do things such as setting the innerHTML and any attributes you would like.

```
var createDivs = function() {
    var body = document.body;
    for(var i = 0, l = 10; i < l; i++)
    {
        var div = document.createElement('div');
        div.innerHtml = 'Some Text'; //set inner html of the div
        div.setAttribute('class', 'testClass'); //set attributes of the div
        body.appendChild(div);
    }
}
```

Here is a jsFiddle Example:

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/LBgDJ/2/)

If you are using jQuery you can do it in the following way.

```
var createDivs = function() {
    var myArray = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10];
    var body = $('body');
    $.each(myArray,function(index, value) {
        body.append($('<div class="testClass" id="' + index + '">Some Text</div>'));
    });
}
```

Here is a JSFiddle example of that

[JSFiddle jQuery Example](http://jsfiddle.net/Cj3kq/)